# Tic-Tac-Toe Minimax tree Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, tree, minimax

For uni I have this assignment where I need to make Tic-Tac-Toe in Haskell. The problem I'm facing at the moment is creating a minimax tree, the code I found elsewhere for this problem is the following:

```
minimax :: Player -> Rose Board -> Rose Int
minimax p (MkRose r [])   | hasWinner r == Just p = MkRose 1 []
                          | hasWinner r == Just (nextPlayer p) = MkRose (-1) []
                          | otherwise              = MkRose 0 []

minimax P1 (MkRose r rs) = MkRose (maximum (map root xs)) xs
    where xs = map (minimax P2) rs

minimax P2 (MkRose r rs) = MkRose (minimum (map root xs)) xs
    where xs = map (minimax P1) rs
```

the `hasWinner :: Board -> Maybe Player` gives the winner of a tictactoe board if there is one, and `data Rose a = MkRose a [Rose a]`.

The problem im having is that this function makes the minimax tree from the perspective of P1 (if P1 wins, the outcome is 1, if P2 wins, the outcome is -1) regardless of th player you input in the function. What I need is that if `p = P2`, that games where P1 wins are labeled as -1 and games where P2 wins are labeled as 1. The difficulty is that you can't just flip end values if `p = P2`, because then P1 needs to look for a minimum instead of a maximum, and vice versa. Does anyone know how i could rewrite this function fixing this issue? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Um. Are you sure you want the minimax tree to be from the perspective of the current player? That is definitely nonstandard, and makes building the tree much more expensive, as you need to negate all values at each recursion. (However, your concern about "use minimum instead of maximum" is not an issue: if it is always from the perspective of the current player, you just always use maximum.)

Comment: Also: definitely take a look at the related questions on the right. In particular the "Haskell Recursive Minimax Tree" one that shows up for me looks super related -- probably somebody working on the exact same exercise as you.